# how to segregate files in a blob storage using ADF copy activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a copy data activity in ADF and I want to segregate the files into a different container based on the file type.

ex.
Container A - .jpeg, .png
Container B - .csv, .xml and .doc

My initial idea was to use 'if condition' and 'or' statement but looks like my approach won't work.
I'd appreciate it if you could give some inputs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the list files from the **source container** and loop each file in the `Foreach` activity to check the extension using `If condition` and copy files based on the condition to their respective containers.

I have the below files in my source container.

[image]

**In ADF:**

1. Using the `Get metadata` activity, get the list of all files from the source container.

[image]

2. **Output of Get Metadata activity**:

[image]

3. Pass the output list to `Foreach` activity.

`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems`

[image]

4. Inside the `Foreach` activity, add `If Condition` activity to separate the files based on extension.

`@or(contains(item().name, '.xml'),contains(item().name, '.csv'))`

[image]

5. If the condition is **true**, copy the current file to **container1**.

[image]

[image]

6. If the condition returns **false**, copy the current file to **container2** in False activity.

[image]

[image]

Files in the container after running the pipeline.

**Container1:**

[image]

**Container2:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `GetMetadata` activity to first get all the file types that needs to be first passed to a `CopyData` activity which copies to Container A, and then add next Getmetadata activity to get file types for next copydata activity that copies to container B.
so, your ADF pipeline may be like GetMetaData1 - > Copydata1 -> GetMetaData2 -> Copydata2.  Refer how to use GetMetaData activity in this [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6246/azure-data-factory-get-metadata-example/), and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity)

Copy activity itself allows more than one `wildcard path`, so you could use that in the Data source, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#mapping-data-flow-properties).